# double to BigDecimal results in a 4 instead of 5 in the last place

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I have a double value which is shown as: 
(created from a string exactly like this)

```
2.4284723894328895E13
```

If I run this

```
(new BigDecimal(doubleValue)).toPlainString()
```

I get

```
(java.lang.String) 24284723894328.89453125
```

I am confused. Why are the decimal places `.895` changed into `.89453125` ?
I would not mind to see something like .89499999999 but not such a big difference.
It also changes the expected result when rounding to two decimal places - then resulting in `.89` instead of `.90`) with:

```
bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). That value you created from a string "exactly like this" is not representable exactly as a `double`.

Comment: Also the number gets cut off after "...8895" as a result of being rounded. If you round "...89453125" you end up with "...8895". Double is NOT the way to go if you aim for prescise number representation!

Comment: @JimGarrison: The double pretends to have that value. At least I would not have expected such a big difference (~ 0.00047 ).

Comment: @July, 0.00047 is ~2e-15% of 2.4284723894328895E13. I wouldn't call this "a big difference" ;)

Comment: The difference is the one between `24284723894328.895` and `24284723894328.89453125` The difference is ~.00047 but as a fraction of the magnitude (i.e. percent error) it is microsocopic and insignificant.

Comment: I understand - thank you. I've changed my code and put the string directly in BigDecimal which works nicely as expected